# Changing FLAC channel assignment to decorrelated left-side causes lost sync error status

Tags: audio, encoding, compression, flac, lossless-compression

I have created a minimal stereo FLAC file according to the specifications [here](https://xiph.org/flac/format.html). It is a single block of 8192 samples of 0 encoded as a constant:

```
00000000: 664c 6143 8000 0022 2000 2000 0000 0000
00000010: 0000 0ac4 42f0 0000 0000 bb7d f04e 1b0a
00000020: 2570 6575 27a7 e108 ae23 fff8 d918 0060
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 119a
```

This file is checked as "ok" if I run `flac -t stereo_file.flac`. According to the above linked specification, the high 4 bits of byte `0x18` at `0x2D` indicate channel assignment `0001`, i.e. left and right-channels. If I change that one nybble to `8`, for channel assignment `1000`, or left and side- decorrelated channels (and adjusting the CRC8 at `0x2F` and the CRC16 at `0x36`), I get the following file:

```
00000000: 664c 6143 8000 0022 2000 2000 0000 0000
00000010: 0000 0ac4 42f0 0000 0000 bb7d f04e 1b0a
00000020: 2570 6575 27a7 e108 ae23 fff8 d988 0081
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 a880
```

Except this time, when I run the above `flac` command, it reports:

```
stereo_file.flac: *** Got error code 0:FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_ERROR_STATUS_LOST_SYNC
*** Got error code 0:FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_ERROR_STATUS_LOST_SYNC


stereo_file.flac: ERROR during decoding
           state = FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_END_OF_STREAM
```

I can see no reason why this should give an error, unless there is some kind of nuance or caveat not mentioned in the specifications regarding decorrelation. Is there any way I can tell in greater detail what is causing this error for the second file, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the left, right and mid channels are 16 bit, the side channel needs to be 17 bit, because otherwise the side channel could clip or overflow.

For example, if at a certain point in the stream, the left channel is 32767 (the maximum positive integer when using signed 16-bit) and the right channel is -32768 (the maximum negative integer) the result when using left-side would be a side sample of -65535, which has to be stored with at least 17 bit.

I agree that this is something not mentioned clearly in the FLAC specification. See also [this code on github](https://github.com/xiph/flac/blob/b358381a102a2c1c153ee4cf95dfc04af62faa1a/src/libFLAC/stream_encoder.c#L3337-L3356).

Comment: In the linked code, it looks like mid uses the same bps as left and right, and only side uses the extra bit. If mid holds the average of left and right, rather than their sum, this makes sense, and is consistent with the specifications

Comment: You are right, the mid channel is actually some kind of average: https://github.com/xiph/flac/blob/b358381a102a2c1c153ee4cf95dfc04af62faa1a/src/libFLAC/stream_encoder.c#L2202-L2203 I will change the answer accordingly